# Java8 Stream fails inside custom SWT listener on terminal operation in parallel stream

Tags: java-8, swt

Java8 Stream fails inside custom SWT listener on terminal operation.
Succeeds when used in a native, implemented listener.

Primary difference is that one is applied using **org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setMenu(Menu menu)**. I get a feeling this is an invalid thread access issue having to do with how Java8 creates Parallel Stream threads using a threadpool.

Exception caught:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Unspecified error
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateParallel(Unknown Source)
```

Working instance:

```
@Override
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.widget instanceof Table) {
            tableRightClicked = (Table) e.widget;
            rightClickLocation = new Point(e.x, e.y);

            if(e.button != 1){//user right clicked table! display tableMenu
                if(Constants.debug)System.out.println("RIGHT MOUSE BUTTON CLICKED IN TABLE");
                Stream<ToolsetAvailability> resourceAvail = scenarioMap.get("5-Year Mar. 2016 1. Single Source").availabilityData.parallelStream().filter(availability -> availability.resourceID.equals("3004"));
                System.out.println("resourceAvail count:"+resourceAvail.count());
```

Failing instance:

```
public SelectionListener menuSelectionListener = new SelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                Stream<ToolsetAvailability> resourceAvail = scenarioMap.get("5-Year Mar. 2016 1. Single Source").availabilityData.parallelStream().filter(availability -> availability.resourceID.equals("3004"));
                System.out.println("resourceAvail count:"+resourceAvail.count());
}
```

--- the code works with single thread stream, so is access to the custom listener blocking for extra threads? And why only on terminal operations?

Comment: What does the SWT documentation say regarding access from multiple threads?

Comment: developed question further.

Comment: Do you have a clear rationale for using parallel streams in the first place, or is it just because it "seemed like a good idea"?  GUI toolkits generally use thread-confinement extensively; here, you're spraying execution across random threads, which are then probably accessing things that are supposed to be confined to the GUI thread.  This is almost certainly the problem.  Lesson: parallelism is an advanced tool for advanced situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think (tentatively) there are two problems here: there is whatever is causing the java parallel stream to call `reportException`, which might be something minor or obvious, and then there's something bad happening when it tries to create the exception, right down in the native code layer of the java platform. It looks like it's trying to instantiate a native SWT exception class via reflection and failing.

I would gather that the whole scenarioMap / ToolsetAvailability stuff is part of your application domain separate from the GUI. If there is SWT-specific code inside there, that might be the problem; the native GUI layer may not like instantiating GUI objects in unexpected threads.

Otherwise, I assume you have checked that the code works using `availabilityData.stream()` instead of `availabilityData.parallelStream()`? If not, doing that may show you the root error that isn't being reported in the parallel case because of the other problems.

Comment: I believe you are on to something - java8 parallel streams use common fork-join thread pool from [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) class. Is there some extra flagging done on parallel threads in java8 because it uses a threadpool?

Comment: Marking as answer for sake of completed-ness. Cheers